# Using constants in gruntjs

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to write my first Grunt task to copy some files from my common libs folder, which is out of my project directory.

- Project Folder : `/home/user/projects/bottle`
- Common Libs directory : `/home/user/projects/common`
- Files' source are inside Common Libs directory at : `lib/general/static/js/`
- Files' destination inside project folder : `lib`

I have a `properties.json` file with Common Libs directory path as shown below

```
{
    "common_libs" : `/home/user/projects/common`
}
```

Now what I already tried is :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var properties = grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json'),
        paths = {
            common_libs : properties.common_libs,
            common_libs_js : this.common_libs + "lib/general/static/js/"
        };

    grunt.initConfig({
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        flatten : true,
                        src: [
                            paths.common_libs_js + "/*"
                        ],
                        dest: 'lib/',
                        filter: 'isFile'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

I am running grunt as follows
`grunt copy`

With this no files are copied to the destination.

Help me in this.

Also I want to know

1. How can I use Ant's property tag type constants in GruntJS? Because I am getting the base folder from properties.json and I need to copy many files from different folders under the base folder.
2. Can we have these type of constants per task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. First:

```
common_libs_js : this.common_libs + "lib/general/static/js/"
```

Unfortunately `this.common_libs` is undefined (`this` doesn't point to where you think it does), so common_libs_js ends up being `'undefinedlib/general/static/js/'`, which doesn't work.

The second problem is that on that same line you are concatenating paths, but the first path (from the properties file) doesn't seem to end with a slash, and would become `'/home/user/projects/commonlib/general/static/js/'` if it wasn't for the previous issue.

Third, you'd get a whole bunch of folders inside your dest path. When the expand option is used, Grunt uses the paths as given in the src property to create the folder structure. If you want `/home/user/projects/common/lib/general/static/js/foo.js` to be copied to `lib/foo.js`, you should set the `cwd` option to `paths.common_libs_js` and the src to `'*.js'` (or `'**/*.js'` for a match on any level).

People usually embed configuration properties inside Grunt's config, and then use template strings to access them. A very common way to write your task would be something like this (with a few changes, adjust as needed):

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        properties: grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json'),
        copy: {
            main: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= properties.common_libs %>/lib/general/static/js',
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'lib'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

Alternatively, if you want your files to end up in '`lib/general/static/js/`' in the destination path too:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        properties: grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json'),
        copy: {
            main: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= properties.common_libs %>',
                src: 'lib/general/static/js/**/*.js',
                dest: '.' // because src includes 'lib'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

If you're not sure how Grunt sees your files, run it with `grunt -v` and it will tell you.

You might also want to consider git submodules for a non-Grunt solution.

For task-specific constants: you could use the task's (or target's) `options` hash for that, and access it with template strings:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        properties: grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json'),
        copy: {
            options: {
                foo: 'lib'
            },
            main: {
                options: {
                    bar: '**/*.js'
                },
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= properties.common_libs %>/<%= copy.options.foo %>/general/static/js',
                src: '<%= copy.options.main.bar %>',
                dest: 'lib'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

This is rarely done for anything other than actual options, though. Conflicts with real options can occur. You could also use the target namespace directly, setting the property directly inside `main`. But again, there are a few property names that may conflict.

If you want to override properties (e.g. for a release build), you can do this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.registerTask('release', function() {
        grunt.config.set('properties.common_libs', '/usr/lib/shared');
    });

    grunt.initConfig({
        properties: grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json'),
        copy: {
            main: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= properties.common_libs %>/lib/general/static/js',
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'lib'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

Then you'd call your task with `grunt release copy`.

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question, it doesn't seem like the `properties.json` file is of much use to you. Why not just specify the properties in your Gruntfile?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        properties: {
            base_dir: '../common',
            base_js_dir: '<%= properties.base_dir %>/lib/general/static/js',
            base_css_dir: '<%= properties.base_dir %>/lib/general/static/css'
        },
        copy: {
            main: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= properties.base_js_dir %>',
                src: '**/*.js',
                dest: 'lib'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
};
```

You can also use the file together with this, if you want. Or even put these properties (with the template strings) inside the `properties.json` file. In the end it's just a matter of making Grunt see an object with template strings. It's up to you to provide that somehow.

Comment: Thanks @simo-kinnunen. Thanks for the detailed explanation and also for correcting me. What I was looking is, is there anything that I can create another simple variable from `properties.common_libs` so that I don't need to specify a long name in `cwd`. I want `cwd` to take a simple constant something like `properties.common_libs_js`. Because I have many other files to be copied from other folders from the same `properties.common_libs_js`. In Ant we create a new property from the existing one and use that shortcut. I am looking for a similar one. Can we achieve this in GruntJS?

Comment: I would like to point out one more small but convenient thing-

If you are using some thing of the sore '/home/user/...' it is better to use process.env.HOME, assuming that the HOME variable is set in your path. This makes your code usable by another developer who might have this file in say '/home/otherUser/...' without modifying the path.