# Make Global Objects in Grunt

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to use the includereplace plugin for grunt. I'm trying to give it values for `globals` property by fetching a JSON using the code below:

```
grunt.registerTask('fetchProperties', 'Fetches the properties.json file', function() {
    properties = grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json');
    grunt.log.writeln(['Properties file loaded']);
});
```

Now when I do `properties.var_a` it returns the value of `var_a` correctly.
So, I did this:

```
 grunt.registerTask('fetchProperties', 'Fetches the properties.json file', function() {
    properties = grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json');
    grunt.task.run('includereplace');
})
```

Here is my includereplace task:

```
includereplace: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                globals: {
                    VAR_A: properties.var_a, 
                    VAR_B: properties.var_b
                },
            },
            files: [{
                src: '../myFiles/path/to/some/file/main.txt',
                dest: '../myOtherFiles/path/to/some/file/mainrep.txt'
            }]
        }
    }
```

Now the values being replaced by the `includereplace` task are `undefined`.
How to mitigate this problem?
Also, I have tried setting the variables using `grunt.config` but the thing is, I have a JSON file which on loading will return an object and not a single value. How to set a global object which can be used by all the tasks at execution for setting their parameters?
I'm loading the JSON file at the start of the grunt file. It is the first line inside my `module.exports = function(grunt) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked!

```
grunt.initConfig({
    properties: grunt.file.readJSON('properties.json'),
    includereplace: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            globals: {
                VAR_A: '<%= properties.var_a %>', 
                VAR_B: '<%= properties.var_b %>'
            },
        },
        files: [{
            src: '../myFiles/path/to/some/file/main.txt',
            dest: '../myOtherFiles/path/to/some/file/mainrep.txt'
        }]
    }
  }
});
```

Used https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792592/2459789 for this.